# How can i set my own images in whatsapp wallpaper?

Tags: android, list, android-intent, intentservice, whatsapp

Hi I want to develop a small app. In that when a user click the wallpaper option in the whatsapp I want to add my app to the list of whatsapp. In my app if I select any image that image will be set as a wallpaper in whatsapp.

I have tried the with intent. But I didn't succeed. can you please help me how can I achieve that.

For the ref I am sharing the image.[image]

Comment: Have you found the solution then pls answer here !

Comment: its not that what you actually want, but in case if you are looking for customized intent list https://github.com/shanrais/Android-Custom-Intent-List